# PhoneGap App always open context menu on start

Tags: android, cordova

I've made some differents Apps with PhoneGap, and ALWAYS when running the App (on the AVD emulator and the Android Phone itself) when the App is starting, it's like someone press the "Android Context Menu Button" that opens a Context Menu...

I've been searching a lot, but I have not found a solution. Anyone knows why this is happening to me?

(It doesn't happen with the "Hello World" App that comes by default)

The only plugin I have in the Plugin Folder it's android.json (which is the platform plugin I believe)

And here's the  part of the App with the definitions...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-density dpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<title>Ctrl</title>
<script src="js/debug.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add code snippet of your code?

Comment: of what function? it happens in every App I made!!! XD

Comment: Are you using any plugins? How are you initialising your app? Unless someone reads this who's had your exact problem (and I've never heard of it before) you'll have to update your question with some code.

Comment: there it is! I posted the definitions (which I suspect may be the problem here)